# Mulesoft conditional statement

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have an XML and I want to check in Dataweave if a `<custom-attribute attribute-id="sscAccountid">0011x0000152nlyAAA</custom-attribute>` tag exist in XML, how to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31" order-no="00001503">
        <order-date>2020-07-24T13:15:09.654Z</order-date>
        <created-by>storefront</created-by>
        <original-order-no>000015034</original-order-no>
        <customer>
            <customer-no>00000001</customer-no>
            <billing-address>
                <first-name>abc</first-name>
                <last-name>Chioda</last-name>
                <address1>via Venezia 55</address1>
                <phone>+444</phone>
            </billing-address>
        </customer>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_pspReference">882595596510490G</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_value">29999</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscAccountid">0011x0000152nlyAAA</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscSyncResponseText">
                <value>Successfully Exported</value>
            </custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscSyncStatus">exported</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscid">8011x00000QaOFwAAN</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
</order>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to confirm if an XML payload with the structure of your example has an order.custom-attributes.custom-attribute element with attribute attribute-id equal "sscAccountid".

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun hasAccountId(x) =sizeOf(x.order.'custom-attributes'  filterObject ($.@'attribute-id' == "sscAccountid") ) > 0
---
hasAccountId(payload)
```

Output for your input XML:

```
true
```

Comment: I am trying to add this expression to var component of mulesoft but It gives error : `"Unexpected character combination '</' in epilog (extra close tag?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [160,2], while reading `payload` as Xml.
 [row,col]: [160,2]
Trace:
  at sizeOf (line: 1, column: 43)
  at main (line: 1, column: 1)" evaluating expression: "sizeOf(payload.order.'custom-attributes'  filterObject ($.@'attribute-id' == "sscAccountid") ) > 0".`

Comment: Looks like your input is not valid XML. It has an extra `</` closing tag.

Comment: true, now I fix that but getting another error`"Trying to output non-whitespace characters outside main element tree (in prolog or epilog), while writing Xml at ." evaluating expression: "sizeOf(payload.order.'custom-attributes'  filterObject ($.@'attribute-id' == "sscAccountid") )"` expression I am using now in var component is is `sizeOf(payload.order.'custom-attributes'  filterObject ($.@'attribute-id' == "sscAccountid") )`, haven't defined any mime type though